# If inside return

Tags: javascript, function, return, shorthand

Is it possible to add `if` condition into `return` so that depending on the Boolean value `flag`

it was returned inside the function like

```
return { val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb'}
```

or

```
return { val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb', val3:'ccc'}.
```

Of course I can do

```
if (flag) {
    return { val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb'}
} else {
    return { val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb', val3:'ccc'}.
}
```

however I don't like it as there are too many properties (not just `val1`, `val2` as here in the example but many many more) so there is a huge block that will be duplicated in this case.

Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a frequent problem.

The clean solution is to declare your object:

```
var vals = { val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb'};
if (flag) vals.val3 = 'ccc';
return vals;
```

It's also what mimics the underlying logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var obj = { val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb'};

if (!flag) {
  obj.val3 = 'ccc';
  //any other changes to the object you might want to add  
}

return obj;
```

If you have many properties you might try to `extend` your basic object with an object containing extra properties, for example using [jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Answer (score 1):

With underscore you can do something like this:

```
return _.extend({ val1: 'aaa', val2: 'bbb' }, flag ? {} : { val3: 'ccc' });
```